# remove whitespace from all items in a directory and sub directory

Tags: bash, files, rename, recursive

I have a directory which contains files and sub directories, some of which have whitespace in their names. Further more each of these sub directories contains files with whitespace in their names. Is there a simple way to remove the whitespace from all the names in the parent directory and all sub directories at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to remove the whitespace from all the names in the parent directory and all sub directories at once?

Yes there is:

```
find /tmp/ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

[Further Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/bash-script-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `find` command to enumerate the files you need to rename. Select only file names with spaces for performance. Pass the `-depth` option to act on files in subdirectories before acting on the directory itself, since renaming the directories as `find` is traversing them will result in some directories being missed.

```
find /path/to/directory -depth -name '* *' -exec … {} +
```

If you have the [`prename`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=prename) command, it applies a Perl expression to rename files. You need to take care to act only on the file's base name, not on the whole directory path. If your `find` has the `-execdir` action, that's a convenient way of doing this:

```
find /path/to/directory -name '* *' -execdir prename 's/ //g' {} +
```

Replace `s/ //g` by `s/ /_/g` to replaces spaces by underscores rather than remove them outright, or `s/ +/_/g` to replace sequences of spaces by a single underscore.

Without `-execdir` you need the directory avoidance logic in the Perl code.

```
find /path/to/directory -depth -name '* *' -exec prename '
    s:.*/::; $dir=$&;
    s/ //g;
    $_="$dir$_"
' {} +
```

If you don't have `prename`, you can do this with a shell script. You'll need to invoke a shell from `find`. If you have ksh, you can use its `${file// /}` construct to get the value of the variable `file` with spaces removed (use `${file// /_}` to replace each space by an underscore):

```
find /path/to/directory -depth -name '* *' -execdir ksh -c '
    mv "$0" "${0// /}"
' {} \;
```

or

```
find /path/to/directory -depth -name '* *' -exec ksh -c '
    for file do
      dir=${file%/*};
      file=${x##*/};
      mv "$dir/$file" "$dir/${file// /}";
    done
' _ {} +
```

If you have bash or mksh, you can use it instead of ksh. If you have none, you can use `sed` to do the string processing.

```
find /path/to/directory -depth -name '* *' -exec sh -c '
    for file do
      dir=${file%/*};
      file=${x##*/};
      without_spaces=$(printf %s "$file." | sed "s/ //g")
      mv "$dir/$file" "$dir/${without_spaces%.}";
    done
' _ {} +
```