# Confused by `rename`

Tags: find, rename

I have this list of files:

```
$ find .
.
./   sdf.sdf
./  dkfjd  L
./aaa*
./aaa*bbb
./aaa:bbb
./b
./b/c
./b/c/xxx.123
```

If I do `rename -n -e 's/\*|\:/_/g' -e 's/^\ +//' *` I get what I want:

```
'   sdf.sdf' would be renamed to 'sdf.sdf'
'  dkfjd  L' would be renamed to 'dkfjd  L'
'aaa*' would be renamed to 'aaa_'
'aaa*bbb' would be renamed to 'aaa_bbb'
'aaa:bbb' would be renamed to 'aaa_bbb'
```

But if I do `find . | rename -n -e 's/\*|\:/_/g' -e 's/^\ +//'` I get:

```
Reading filenames from STDIN
'./aaa*' would be renamed to './aaa_'
'./aaa*bbb' would be renamed to './aaa_bbb'
'./aaa:bbb' would be renamed to './aaa_bbb'
```

Why does the 2nd command NOT see the directories beginning with spaces?

I also tried `find . -print0 | rename -n -0 -e 's/\*|\:/_/g' -e 's/^\ +//'` but that made no difference.

I need to run the `rename` on a large tree; is there some other way to recurse into subdirectories?

Note: ultimately I will be using this with `mdfind` not `find` so I can't use the `-exec` option.

Comment: because `find` prints filename with `./` at start?

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215124/remove-whitespace-from-all-items-in-a-directory-and-sub-directory?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

This will rename files and directories (well, anything that matches, really). I've specified `-depth` so that higher level directories aren't renamed until the contents have been safely processed.

```
find . -depth | rename -n -e 'y{*:}{_}; s{(?<=/)\s+(?!.*/.*$)}{}'
```

The rename is built from two REs. (My `rename` accepts only one `-e {RE}` argument so I've concatenated the two operations into the single parameter.)

The first is straightforward: `y{*:}{_}` substitutes either `*` or `:` for `_` (aka Unix `tr`).

The second is more complicated and uses [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the necessary component. It says that the expression `\s+` to be processed is to be immediately preceded by `/`, and must not be followed by `/` anywhere in the rest of the filename.

Output

```
rename(./  dkfjd  L, ./dkfjd  L)
rename(./aaa*, ./aaa_)
rename(./aaa*bbb, ./aaa_bbb)
rename(./   sdf.sdf, ./sdf.sdf)
rename(./aaa:bbb, ./aaa_bbb)
```